# ie7 Expected identifier, string or number with AJAX function

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I ma using `AJAX` to update a database and it works well on all browsers except `IE7`.  Before I give up and decide that users `IE7` should be asked to upgrade I thought I'd check and make sure I'm not missing something obvious seeing as I'm very new to `AJAX`.

Script debugging throws an error saying '`SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number`' identifying the offending character as the second to last curly brace

```
<script>
  function save_pos_reasons()
  {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save_pos_reasons.php",
    data: $('#add_positioning').serialize(),
    });
 }
</script>
```

And when I try to run the function it says

`SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'save_pos_reasons' is null or undefined, not a function object`.

and identifies the line below as the cause.

```
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Save" onClick="save_pos_reasons()"/>
```

I am beginning to wonder if it is the `JQuery serialize function` that it is struggling with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to get rid of the trailing comma.

```
data: $('#add_positioning').serialize(), //this comma is the culprit
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue straight away